# How to get p_values of features in survreg?

Tags: r

I working on survival analysis and each time I use a different test set and at the end I would like to have the avg of coefficients, p for each feature and p value of the model. I can get coefficients using srFit$coefficients. But I don't know how to get the p values, although I can see them using summary(srFit).

```
summary(srFit)

Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(time) ~ f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 + f5 + f6 + f7 + f8 + f9 + f10, data = train, dist = dist_pred[i_dist])
                            Value Std. Error       z        p
(Intercept)              1.59e+03   632.0632  2.5092 1.21e-02
f1                      -2.07e+00     1.2283 -1.6881 9.14e-02
f2                       1.03e+00     1.8070  0.5677 5.70e-01
f3                      -7.61e-02     1.3764 -0.0553 9.56e-01
f4                      -3.24e+00     1.4836 -2.1843 2.89e-02
f5                       4.37e-01     0.0961  4.5474 5.43e-06
f6                      -1.36e+00     0.7555 -1.8011 7.17e-02
f7                      -6.26e-03     0.0081 -0.7719 4.40e-01
f8                       3.92e-03     0.0186  0.2111 8.33e-01
f9                      -4.82e-01     0.4291 -1.1235 2.61e-01
f10                     -7.79e-01     0.3139 -2.4809 1.31e-02
Log(scale)               2.73e+00     0.0314 86.9447 0.00e+00

Scale= 15.4 

Student-t distribution: parmameters= 4
Loglik(model)= -4542.1   Loglik(intercept only)= -4570.1
    Chisq= 56 on 10 degrees of freedom, p= 2.1e-08 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 5 
n= 1008
```

Comment: Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at `survival:::summary.survreg`, you can see how the p-values are computed, i.e.

`table <- matrix(rep(coef, 4), ncol = 4)
        dimnames(table) <- list(cname, c("Value", "Std. Error", 
            "z", "p"))
        stds <- sqrt(diag(object$var))
        table[, 2] <- stds
        table[, 3] <- table[, 1]/stds
        table[, 4] <- 2 * pnorm(-abs(table[, 3]))`

is the table that is actually printed. In other words, the p-values can be obtained from your `survreg` object with

`with(srFit, 2*pnorm(-abs(coefficients / sqrt(diag(var)))) )`